# Mocking the "save" method on domain classes

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I'm having hard time mocking the save instance method in my unit tests in Grails 1.3.3. I've created a simple domain class named Person, it has one property (nullable) called "name".

```
package tutorial

class Person {

    String name

    static constraints = {
        name nullable: true
    }
}
```

In my test I'm trying to do something I've found in the documentation:

```
class PersonTests extends GrailsUnitTestCase {
    public void testCanSavePerson() {
        def testInstances = []
        mockDomain(Person, testInstances)
        assertEquals(0, Person.count())
        new Person(name: "Bob").save()
        assertEquals(1, Person.count())
    }
}
```

However as soon as I run the test what I get is an exception:

java.lang.NullPointerException
at grails.test.MockUtils$_addValidateMethod_closure83.doCall(MockUtils.groovy:973)
at grails.test.MockUtils$_addValidateMethod_closure84.doCall(MockUtils.groovy:1014)
at grails.test.MockUtils$_addDynamicInstanceMethods_closure67.doCall(MockUtils.groovy:736)
at grails.test.MockUtils$_addDynamicInstanceMethods_closure67.doCall(MockUtils.groovy)
at tutorial.PersonTests.testCanSavePerson(PersonTests.groovy:25)

whereas the line 25 is exactly the one that calls save() on newly created instance.

Does anyone knows what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oddly enough it works with 1.3.2 and 1.3.1... I guess I'll have to file a bug report for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an already known bug in Grails 1.3.3. Read more about it and find a workaround in the associated JIRA ticket [GRAILS-6482](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-6482).